# ASP.NET Reusable Handlers and Session State

Tags: asp.net, handler

Can an ASP.NET Handler (.ashx) that implements `IRequiresSessionState` be reusable or will it persist its relationship with the first Session used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be reusable.

Callers pass session state inside the `HttpContext` when they invoke the `ProcessRequest` method. Method parameters are only available within the scope of each method invocation, not across multiple invocations on different threads.

Ultimately, it depends on your [`ProcessRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx) implementation, but unless you do something very unusual (like store the session in a member variable and then use it later during the method call), each request will use the correct session even though they're sharing the handler instance.

Comment: I don't actually use the HttpContext passed into ProcessRequest, but I had to implement IRequiresSessionState as I am making a call to a static method elsewhere which itself uses HttpContext.Current.Session.  From what you've said I believe that my handler can be reusable.  Thanks.